# Get Grunt to upload files after watch is triggered

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am working on a site that uses SCSS. We have grunt watching those files to convert them to css but each time we make a change we have to tab over to the css file and upload. Maybe not a big deal but over time on different projects it adds up.

I would like the watch process to run ftpush once it see's a change but the only times I've got it to work it stays on ftpush which means we have to exit grunt then run it again. It would be helpful if after the upload os complete(or a specific time passes) it resumes the watch task.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
        options: {
            loadPath: ['bower_components/foundation/scss'],
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: {
                'assets/css/app.css': 'assets/scss/app.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    ftpush: {
        build: {
            auth: {
                host: 'OUR HOST',
                port: 21,
                authKey: 'key1'
            },
            src: '../vhc-master',
            dest: '/var/www/html/vhc/dev/wp-content-themes/vhc-master'
        }
    },

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
            tasks: ['ftpush'],
            options: {
                interrupt: true,
                reload: true
            }
        },

        sass: {
            files: 'assets/scss/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ftpush');

grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass']);
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['ftpush']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build','watch']);
}
```